# Unable to include Bootstrap using npm in angular-cli project

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

I am trying to include bootstrap using npm in angular-cli project. After downloading it using npm, I am trying to use it by importing bootstrap.scss in styles.scss and including jquery and bootstrap.min.js in angular.json.

**styles.scss**

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

**angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

On compiling the code, getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Can't resolve 'functions' in 'C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\bootstrap\scss'
    at doResolve (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:180:19)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn5 (eval at create (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:57:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:37)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn1 (eval at create (C:\EMS\prac-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Please check your bootstrap scss path in NodeModules, I think it should be inside dist folder. your path will be "bootstrap/dist/scss/bootstrap.scss"

Comment: In styles.scss: `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/scss/bootstrap.scss"`

Comment: may u should consider to not use plain bootstrap because of jquery is not designed to work properly whit angular. Use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home which is bootstrap for angular whit out jquery.

Comment: This should do @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Comment: I think you are doing wrong base on  your console error `./src/styles.css` you are importing `scss` file in `css` please check your `styles` file extension

Answer (score 2):

Try to use relative path in the scss file and remove `scss` extension:

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

this works for me

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is with the path of the CSS file, try changing paths of file like below:

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "../src/styles.css"
    ],
```

or the issue may occur if you forgot to run npm install